# HLSL: Index to unaligned/packed floats

Tags: xna, shader, hlsl, vertex-shader

I have a vertex shader (2.0) doing some instancing - each vertex specifies an index into an array.

If I have an array like this:

```
float instanceData[100];
```

The compiler allocates it 100 constant registers. Each constant register is a `float4`, so it's allocating 4 times as much space as is needed.

I need a way to make it allocate just 25 constant registers and store four values in each of them.

Ideally I'd like a method where it still looks like a `float[]` on both the CPU and GPU (Right now I am calling `EffectParamter.SetValue(Single[])`, I'm using XNA). But manually packing and unpacking a `float4[]` is an option, too.

Also: what are the performance implications for doing this? Is it actually worth it? (For me, this will save about one batch in every four or five).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does that helps?:

```
float4 packedInstanceData[25];
...
float data = packedInstanceData[index / 4][index % 4];
```

Comment: Yes, this works, thanks. Handy to know that you can index into sub-elements. For reference - in my situation doing this indexing takes 14 instruction slots and 4 constant registers.