# How do you count registers in HLSL?

Tags: graphics, xna, 3d, hlsl

With shader model 2.0, you can have 256 constant registers.  I have been looking at various shaders, and trying to figure out what constitutes a single register?

For example, in my instancing shader, I have the following variables declared at the top, outside of functions:

```
float4x4 InstanceTransforms[40];
float4 InstanceDiffuses[40];

float4x4 View;
float4x4 Projection;

float3 LightDirection = normalize(float3(-1, -1, -1));
float3 DiffuseLight = 1;
float3 AmbientLight = 0.66; 

float Alpha;

texture Texture;
```

How many registers have I consumed?  How do I count them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each constant register is a `float4`.

`float3`, `float2` and `float` will each allocate a whole register. `float4x4` will use 4 registers. Arrays will simply multiply the number of registers allocated by the number of elements. And the compiler will probably allocate a few registers itself to use as constants in various calculations.

The only way to really tell what the shader is using is to disassemble it. To that end you may be interested in this question that I asked a while ago: [HLSL: Enforce Constant Register Limit at Compile Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863575/hlsl-enforce-constant-register-limit-at-compile-time)

You might also find this one worth a look: [HLSL: Index to unaligned/packed floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866778/hlsl-index-to-unaligned-packed-floats). It explains why an array of 40 `float`s will use 40 registers, and how you can make it use 10 instead.

Your `texture` will use a texture sampler (you have 16 of these), not a constant register.

For reference, here are the list of [ps_2_0 registers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172918(v=VS.85).aspx) and [vs_2_0 registers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172961(v=VS.85).aspx).

Comment: In my pixel shader, I have a float[] called kernel. Upping the length of this array increases registers used, which makes sense. Using if(kernel[i] != 0) in a loop also dramatically increases the registers used. Do you know why would this be?